# Yii2 Mariadb transaction commits fine, but nothing gets stored in DB

Tags: php, yii2, mariadb

I have a code:

```
$tx = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
try {
  // CODE (a lot of active-record reads and writes)
  $tx->commit();
  echo "All good!";
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
  $tx->rollback();
  echo "Error";
}
```

It executes and I get "All good!" as a result.
However, nothing gets actually stored in database.
The code has been working for several months so far and wasn't modieid.
It suddently stopped working yesterday.

After an hour of debugging, I can confirm operations go fine, I can "echo" intermidate results, including IDs of the records I'm inserting. But still nothing saves in DB after the final commit.

If I remove transaction, the code works, and everything gets stored in DB, as it used to with Transaction around.

I want to ensure wholeness of the changes, want to get in back inside the transaction.
Or, at least, I want to understand which code (or DB state or whatever else) prevents data from being stored and why I don't get any exceptions and my "Error" echoed, since transaction failed to commit.

I was sure that if transaction fails to commit (actually write to DB), commit() method would throw an exception, but it does not. Is there a way to get it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Didn't you inspect database logs? Also maybe run out of disk free space?

Comment: Thanks! There is enough space (100Gb+) and memory (7/32Gb taken).
The logs seem to be off, enabling it now.. will try to post as I get them.

Comment: I would suggest checking value of `$tx->level` to make sure you are not in some nested transactions. Also validation errors might cause model to not save but they won't throw exception. But in that case you probably wouldn't be able to get the id of new record.

Comment: And a side note, `$tx = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();` should be before the `try {} catch {}` block because if the exception is thrown in `beginTransaction()` you will try to call `rollback()` on undefined `$tx`.

Comment: Thanks, @MichalHynčica, I edited the code sample above, it actually was above the "try".
Also, every AR save is coded like `if (!$ar->save()) { throw Exception('save failed'); }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be in the code.
Thanks, @Michal Hynčica, you were right indeed.
There was a part like:

```
foreach (..) {
  $tx = Yii->$app->db->beginTransaction();
  if ($oneRareCondition) {
    continue;
  }

  ...
  $tx->commit();
}
```

Was solved by adding `$tx->commit();` before `continue;` in that rarely-happening `if`:

```
foreach (..) {
  $tx = Yii->$app->db->beginTransaction();
  if ($oneRareCondition) {
    $tx->commit();
    continue;
  }

  ...
  $tx->commit();
}
```